# Including hyperlink in QMessageBar

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to include a hyperlink in the messageBar?

I used this to create a simple message:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", 'someHyperlink', Qgis.Info, 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From W3 Schools I found out that you can use html syntax:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", '<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>', Qgis.Info, 0)
```

[image]