# Prevent QMessageBar from closing when clicking on hyperlink?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Follow-up from this question: [Including hyperlink in QMessageBar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437845/including-hyperlink-in-qmessagebar)

Is it possible to stop the QMessageBar from closing when the hyperlink is clicked?

A simple messagebar snippet I am using:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", '<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>', Qgis.Info, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of displaying a hyperlink in the `QgsMessageBar`, I use the method `pushWidget` to display a QLabel that has a hyperlink, so when you click, the message bar won't close.

Here's the code :

```py
# create the Qt Label
link_label = QLabel(
    '<a href="https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438269/93097">'
    "Visit and vote for this awesome answer !</a>"
)
# it can now open your favorite internet browser
link_label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
# display the iface messagebar with the label
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(link_label)
```

---

*Documentation*

- `QgsMessageBar` : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMessageBar.html?#module-QgsMessageBar
- Qt5 `QLabel` : https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qlabel.html

Comment: This works great! Also nice touch to your answer :-)